# how to load data website in value input html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having this piece of code, to load data form PHP in hosting. Then I am displaying received data to value input :

```
$("#MerekDagang").load("http://jiyo-hotel.com/bpom/data.php?id=1&act=Get_MerekDagang").value;
```

The question is how to load data and insert as a input value here:

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='Merek_Dagang' placeholder='Merek Dagang' id='MerekDagang' value=''>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you want to add this?

Comment: I just want to display the data from the web to the input value. if use <div id = 'Merek Dagang'> </ div> data appear. @HimanshuUpadhyay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to use the `.load` method in jquery. It's trying to load the data result into that element tag (which is not a wrapping element, it's a singular input element).

You should use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://jiyo-hotel.com/bpom/data.php?id=1&act=Get_MerekDagang",function(data){
        $("#MerekDagang").val(data);
    });
});
```

This explicitly tells where that data should go (into the val of the element selected).

P.S.: I'm not sure why you would want to immediately load data in through ajax like this though... seems inefficient, where you could have put that data in during the php output build.

Comment: hehehe i make apps with html for sampling :p